# CSS3 animation starts too fast

Tags: html, css, animation

I made 3 divs fade over into eachother, each lasting 7 seconds, so in total 21s.

div 2 has a delay of -7s, div3 has -14s.

Upon entering the website the first div scoots by in less than 7 seconds and when that one fades out everything works like it should, this gives me some problems when trying to animate other things together with that div. Like the frontend developer '' svg doesn't look properly and the timer circle below is 3.5 seconds behind.

How do I get the animations to start with the 7s timer like it should?

EDIT: made a codepen; apparently it starts with the third div, and then it starts with div 1.
You can see it lasts a few seconds, and then it moves to div 1 and from then on every div has a 7s delay. it's only the first time it fails.

#### Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOGJZ

#### CSS

```
.fade-in{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 21s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 21s;
}

.fade-in-2{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade2;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 21s;
    animation-name: fade2;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 21s;
}

.fade-in-3{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade3;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 21s;
    animation-name: fade3;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 21s;
}

.fade-in-2 img, .fade-in-2 svg{
    margin-top:-8em;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    17% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    47% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    17% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    47% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade2 {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    15% {opacity: 0;}
    17% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    45% {opacity: 1;}
    48% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fade2 {
   0% {opacity: 0;}
    15% {opacity: 0;}
    17% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    45% {opacity: 1;}
    48% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

#f1 .fade-in {
}
#f2 .fade-in, #f2 .fade-in-2{
    -webkit-animation-delay: -14s;
}
#f3 .fade-in, #f3 .fade-in-2{
    -webkit-animation-delay: -7s;
}

.frontend-left, .frontend-right, .frontend-dash{
    stroke-dasharray: 500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  animation: dash 7s cubic-bezier(.1, .85, .15, .5) infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.timeline{
      stroke-dasharray: 607;
      stroke-dashoffset: 607;
  animation: dash3 21s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash3 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="content-container service-wrapper">
    <div id="f1" class="service-section">
        <div class="col eentweede fade-in">
            <h2>Div 1</h2>
            <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet             rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        </div>       
        <div class="col eentweede img-here fade-in-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="f2" class="service-section">
        <div class="col eentweede fade-in">
            <h2>Div 2</h2>
            <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col eentweede img-here fade-in-2">
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="f3" class="service-section">
        <div class="col eentweede fade-in" style="text-align:right;">
            <h2>Div 3</h2>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col eentweede img-here fade-in-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: made a codepen! sorry about that

Comment: Not convinced that codepen qualifies for "minimal". Please also post the relevant parts of the code directly in your question.

Comment: Also, what is it exactly you would like to get, and how is what you get different from what you want? It's not really clear from your question.

Comment: Why are your `delay`s negative? That will cause your animation to start mid-progress.

Comment: @jcaron Is it better now? Bassicly: I have 3 divs that each last 7 seconds- except when I start up the page. Upon startup div 3 is already present and fades out after about 3.5 seconds.

Comment: @AndréDion When I make the ' delay ' s positive, it still takes about 3.5 seconds before div 1 appears. (so I don't see anything at all with positive delay)

Comment: @tehchriis, still clearly not "minimal". You include lots of classes that are not defined in your CSS, there are probably way too many elements in your HTML, and your CSS includes lots of rules that are, I believe, not relevant to the issue. If you want people to help you, please consider they don't have time to sort through all your code to find what is relevant and what isn't. Your HTML probably does not need to be more than 9 lines long to illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with your keyframe percentages. You're only viewing the animation for about 20% of it's total duration, the rest of the time it's opacity is 0. Adjust those and make your delay positive and you should see better results.

try this for your keyframes:

```
0% {opacity: 0;}
17% {opacity: 1;}
20% {opacity: 1;}
33% {opacity: 1;}
47% {opacity: 1;}
50% {opacity: 1;}
98% {opacity: 1}
100% {opacity: 0;}
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it, or rather- you fixed it! That was pretty dumb I dind't figure that out myself, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would have just used the delay property in CSS:

```
animation-delay: 2s;
```

You can check out more on animation delays

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

That way you dont need so many keyframes and you can delay it to the time you want.